# Filtering array with TextInput is not working

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, react-native, filter

I'm developing the feature in which when the user type in the `TextInput`and it filters the items in the array `data` and shows in the `FlatList` the result of the search, at the moment it works when I start typing the first time I render the screen, but when I start cancelling the text in the `TextInput` and try again it just returns empty arrays, and nothing shows in the `FlatList`, and also in `useEffect` I get the same array twice.

**Array**

```
Array [
  Object {
    "additional": Array [
      Object {
        "data": Array [
          Object {
            "id": 0,
            "price": 1,
            "selected": false,
            "title": "Ranch",
            "type": "Sides",
          },
          Object {
            "id": 1,
            "price": 1,
            "selected": false,
            "title": "Blue Cheese",
            "type": "Sides",
          },
          Object {
            "id": 2,
            "price": 1,
            "selected": false,
            "title": "Tomato Sauce",
            "type": "Sides",
          },
        ],
        "id": 0,
        "required": false,
        "title": "Sides",
      },
    ],
    "description": "vsjvnmvimrivmeirv",
    "id": 0.101,
    "image": "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1623653387945-2fd25214f8fc?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1170&q=80",   
    "price": 6.95,
    "title": "Garlic Knots",
  },
  Object {
    "additional": Array [
      Object {
        "data": Array [
          Object {
            "id": 0,
            "price": 1,
            "selected": false,
            "title": "Ranch",
            "type": "Sides",
          },
          Object {
            "id": 1,
            "price": 1,
            "selected": false,
            "title": "Blue Cheese",
            "type": "Sides",
          },
          Object {
            "id": 2,
            "price": 1,
            "selected": false,
            "title": "Tomato Sauce",
            "type": "Sides",
          },
        ],
        "id": 0,
        "required": false,
        "title": "Sides",
      },
    ],
    "description": "vsjvnmvimrivmeirv",
    "id": 0.102,
    "image": "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1623653387945-2fd25214f8fc?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1170&q=80",   
    "price": 6.95,
    "title": "Mozzerella Sticks",
  },
  Object {
    "additional": Array [
      Object {
        "data": Array [
          Object {
            "id": 0,
            "price": 0,
            "selected": false,
            "title": "Hot Sauce",
            "type": "Sauces",
          },
          Object {
            "id": 1,
            "price": 0,
            "selected": false,
            "title": "Medium Sauce",
            "type": "Sauces",
          },
        ],
        "id": 1,
        "required": true,
        "title": "Sauces",
      },
      Object {
        "data": Array [
          Object {
            "id": 0,
            "price": 1,
            "selected": false,
            "title": "Ranch",
            "type": "Sides",
          },
          Object {
            "id": 1,
            "price": 1,
            "selected": false,
            "title": "Blue Cheese",
            "type": "Sides",
          },
        ],
        "id": 0,
        "required": false,
        "title": "Sides",
      },
    ],
    "description": "vsjvnmvimrivmeirv",
    "id": 0.103,
    "image": "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1623653387945-2fd25214f8fc?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1170&q=80",   
    "price": 6.95,
    "title": "Buffalo Wings",
  },
  Object {
    "additional": Array [
      Object {
        "data": Array [
          Object {
            "id": 0,
            "price": 1,
            "selected": false,
            "title": "Ranch",
            "type": "Sides",
          },
          Object {
            "id": 1,
            "price": 1,
            "selected": false,
            "title": "Blue Cheese",
            "type": "Sides",
          },
          Object {
            "id": 2,
            "price": 1,
            "selected": false,
            "title": "Caesar",
            "type": "Sides",
          },
          Object {
            "id": 3,
            "price": 1,
            "selected": false,
            "title": "Honey Mustard",
            "type": "Sides",
          },
        ],
        "id": 0,
        "required": false,
        "title": "Sides",
      },
    ],
    "description": "vsjvnmvimrivmeirv",
    "id": 0.201,
    "image": "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1512621776951-a57141f2eefd?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1170&q=80",   
    "price": 6.95,
    "title": "Garden Salad",
  },
  Object {
    "additional": Array [
      Object {
        "data": Array [
          Object {
            "id": 0,
            "price": 1,
            "selected": false,
            "title": "Ranch",
            "type": "Sides",
          },
          Object {
            "id": 1,
            "price": 1,
            "selected": false,
            "title": "Blue Cheese",
            "type": "Sides",
          },
          Object {
            "id": 2,
            "price": 1,
            "selected": false,
            "title": "Caesar",
            "type": "Sides",
          },
          Object {
            "id": 3,
            "price": 1,
            "selected": false,
            "title": "Honey Mustard",
            "type": "Sides",
          },
        ],
        "id": 0,
        "required": false,
        "title": "Sides",
      },
    ],
    "description": "vsjvnmvimrivmeirv",
    "id": 0.202,
    "image": "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1512621776951-a57141f2eefd?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1170&q=80",   
    "price": 6.95,
    "title": "Greek Salad",
  },
  Object {
    "additional": Array [
      Object {
        "data": Array [
          Object {
            "id": 0,
            "price": 1,
            "selected": false,
            "title": "Ranch",
            "type": "Sides",
          },
          Object {
            "id": 1,
            "price": 1,
            "selected": false,
            "title": "Blue Cheese",
            "type": "Sides",
          },
          Object {
            "id": 2,
            "price": 1,
            "selected": false,
            "title": "Caesar",
            "type": "Sides",
          },
          Object {
            "id": 3,
            "price": 1,
            "selected": false,
            "title": "Honey Mustard",
            "type": "Sides",
          },
        ],
        "id": 0,
        "required": false,
        "title": "Sides",
      },
    ],
    "description": "vsjvnmvimrivmeirv",
    "id": 0.203,
    "image": "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1512621776951-a57141f2eefd?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1wYWdlfHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1170&q=80",   
    "price": 6.95,
    "title": "Caesar Salad",
  },
]
```

**Screen**

```
function Orders({ navigation, newOrder }) {
   
  const [search, setSearch] = useState("");
  const [filteredDataSource, setFilteredDataSource] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const starCountRef = ref(dbMenu, 'menu');
    onValue(starCountRef, (snapshot) => {
      const data = snapshot.val();  <-------------------------------Array
      if (filteredDataSource.length == 0) {
      data.map((item) => {
        item.data.map((item) => {
          let array = filteredDataSource;
          array.push(item)
          setFilteredDataSource([...array])
        })
      })
     }
    });
    
  }, []);


  const searchFilterFunction = (text) => {
     if (text) {
       const newData = filteredDataSource.filter(function (item) {
         const itemData = item.title
           ? item.title.toUpperCase()
           : "".toUpperCase();
         const textData = text.toUpperCase();
         return itemData.indexOf(textData) > -1;
       });
       setFilteredDataSource(newData);
       setSearch(text);
       setShowSearch(true)
     } else {
       setFilteredDataSource(filteredDataSource);
       setSearch(text);  
     }
  };


    return (
      <View>
           <TextInput
            onChangeText={(text) => searchFilterFunction(text)}
            clearButtonMode='while-editing'
            style={styles.searchAddress}
            placeholder={'Search menu'}
            autoFocus={true}
            value={search}
            returnKeyType='search'
          />
              <FlatList
                data={filteredDataSource}
                keyExtractor={(item) => item.id}
                renderItem={({ item }) => {
                  return (
                    <TouchableOpacity key={item.id} onPress={() =>navigateToItemFromModal(item)}>
                        <Text>{item.title}</Text>
                        <Text>${item.price}</Text>
                    </TouchableOpacity>
                  )
                }} />
     </View>
     )
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

when you type in textInput you are searching from previous filtered data once the filtered data gets empty then all the next search will happen in empty array  and you are just stuck with empty to avoid that take a dummy state which stores original data.

i have modified your code hope this helps

```js
function Orders({ navigation, newOrder }) {
   
  const [search, setSearch] = useState("");
  const [filteredDataSource, setFilteredDataSource] = useState([]);
const [filteredDataOriginal, setfilteredDataOriginal] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const starCountRef = ref(dbMenu, 'menu');
    onValue(starCountRef, (snapshot) => {
      const data = snapshot.val(); 
      if (filteredDataSource.length == 0) {
    let array = [];
      data.map((item) => {
        item.data.map((dataItem) => {
          array.push(dataItem)
        })
      })
          setFilteredDataSource([...array])
          setfilteredDataOriginal([...array])
     }
    });
    
  }, []);


  const searchFilterFunction = (text) => {
     if (text) {
       const newData = filteredDataOriginal.filter(function (item) {
         const itemData = item.title
           ? item.title.toUpperCase()
           : "".toUpperCase();
         const textData = text.toUpperCase();
         return itemData.indexOf(textData) > -1;
       });
       setFilteredDataSource(newData);
       setSearch(text);
       setShowSearch(true)
     } else {
       setFilteredDataSource(filteredDataOriginal);
       setSearch(text);  
     }
  };


    return (
      <View>
           <TextInput
            onChangeText={(text) => searchFilterFunction(text)}
            clearButtonMode='while-editing'
            style={styles.searchAddress}
            placeholder={'Search menu'}
            autoFocus={true}
            value={search}
            returnKeyType='search'
          />
              <FlatList
                data={filteredDataSource}
                keyExtractor={(item) => item.id}
                renderItem={({ item }) => {
                  return (
                    <TouchableOpacity key={item.id} onPress={() =>navigateToItemFromModal(item)}>
                        <Text>{item.title}</Text>
                        <Text>${item.price}</Text>
                    </TouchableOpacity>
                  )
                }} />
     </View>
     )
}
```

Comment: Dheeraj beat me to it but it's a good answer. For what it's worth and if it helps I did a minimal demo of the same thing https://codesandbox.io/s/trusting-bohr-liueo9?file=/src/App.js